# C++ - 2 char array elements into short int

Tags: c++

What I have is this

```
char receivedData[27];
short int twoBytes;
```

What I want is for `twoBytes` to hold the values of `receivedData[14]` and `receivedData[15]`
meaning, if `receivedData[14]==0x07` and `receivedData[15]==0xBB`, the result would be `twoBytes=0x07BB`

Comment: What about `receivedData[14] * 256 + receivedData[15]`?

Comment: Please use `unsigned char` for your buffer to avoid interesting surprises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`twoBytes = receivedData[14] << 8 | receivedData[15];`

`<< 8` means a left shift by 8 digits (binary; or 2 digits hex), essentially multiplicating the value by 64. This means `0x0007` becomes `0x0700`.

`|` will then `or` this with the other value, essentially setting it to `0x07bb`.

Comment: << 8 //left shift 8 bits, not 2.

Comment: Yeah, been typing too fast. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The important part is to left shift the receivedData[14] 8 bits.  Then you can either | or + that value to receivedData[15].  Its important to point out that the type you specfied are likely to cause issues.  Using a char array means each element is at least 8bits, and without specifying unsigned this could mean 1 bit is reserved for the sign.  The bigger concern is that char is not guaranteed to be 8bits, it could be larger.  The same is true of short int, this value is at least 16 bits but could be larger.  Also you would want to use an unsigned short int  It is best to use stdint.h so you can be precise is your variable size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

main() {
  uint8_t receivedData[27];
  uint16_t twoBytes;
  receivedData[14] = 0x07;
  receivedData[15] = 0xBB;

  twoBytes = receivedData[14] << 8;
  twoBytes = twoBytes |  receivedData[15];

  printf("twoBytes %X\n", twoBytes);
}
```

You can check the size of a specific type by:

printf("%zu\n", sizeof(char));

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
Just use logical operators
twoBytes=receivedData[14]; //twobytes=07h
twoBytes=twoBytes<<8; //twobytes=0700h
twoBytes|=receivedData[15]; //twobytes=07BBh
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your application, but `receivedData` smells like data coming from another computer which might be a use-case for `ntohx`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main() {

  uint8_t receivedData[27] {
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xBB,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

  {
    // The ugly way.
    // You have to be sure that the alignment works.
    uint16_t const twoBytes { 
      ntohs( *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>( &receivedData[14] ) ) };
    std::cout << "TB [" << std::hex << twoBytes << "]" << std::endl;
  }

  {
    // The union way
    union {
      uint8_t  rd[2];
      uint16_t s;
    };

    rd[0] = receivedData[14]; rd[1] = receivedData[15];
    uint16_t const twoBytes { ntohs( s ) };
    std::cout << "TB [" << std::hex << twoBytes << "]" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
TB [7bb]
TB [7bb]
```